# how to use module to extend hash class

Tags: ruby, class, module

I want a function to format hash data

```
  class Hash
   # format data just like from redis
    def like_from_redis
      new_hash = {}
      self.each do |key, value|
        new_hash[key.to_s] = value.to_s
      end
      new_hash
    end
  end

 {a: 123, b: 123413}.like_from_redis # => {'a' => '123', 'b' => '123413'}
```

but, i want it like as follow.

```
  module MyHash
    class Hash
      def like_from_redis
        ## the same
      end
    end
  end

 {a: 1, b: 3}.like_from_redis # => {'a' => '1', 'b' => '3'}
```

how to can i do ?

Comment: Intention not clear. You want to create a new class under the name space of `MyHash`?

Answer (score -1):

“All directories under app” does not, of course, include `lib`. you have to add it manually, which can be done in the following way:

```
# config/application.rb

module MyHash
  class Hash 
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) # add this line
  end
end
```

I hope this may solve your issue. If not then kindly refer this link 
[Include vs Extend in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/)